Database normalization
When normalizing table Message, which is a weak entity of table Email, into 2NF, can Message_Name, Message_Description and Message_Type attributes partially depend on Message_ID only?
These attributes are in a weak entity. So they are dependent on composite primary key of message table.


Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions
discouraged? PS Give all that is needed to ask but only what is needed ot ask.

What is your definition of 2NF? What is your justified/published method for normalizing to 2NF & where are you 1st stuck following it? "depend on Message_ID only" is not clear. This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Also it is not clear what your last paragraph has to do with your question. Explain your reasoning clearly. Ask exactly 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. PS 2NF is not useful, we only ever normalize to 2NF for a school assignment.

The compound key that you are looking for is in the message_recipients' table. [person_1] and [person] are the same table.

